# Regular expression, find word in string, but not surrounded by tag

Tags: php, regex

These code find first occurance $word in $text, and replace it by something:

```
<?php
  $text = preg_replace("/\b($word)\b/i", 'something', $text, 1);
?>
```

But i want ignore if this word surrounded by "a" tag, for example, searching should find only second "word" here:

```
<a href="something">text text word text</a>. text2 text2 word text2...
```

Comment: What if `word` is in a `<p>` tag?

Comment: Ah, let's assume only "a" tag...

Comment: Obligatory... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 :)

Comment: What if the word is an attribute value: `<a href="/word.html">word</a>`? No regex-hack will be fool-proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [DOM](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) Parser to find all text nodes that contain the needle and which do not have a a parent element with a name of "a":

```
$html = <<< HTML
<p>
    . text2 text2 word text2...
    <a href="something">text text word <span> word </span> text</a>
    . text2 text2 word text2...
<p>
HTML;
```

Code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xp->query('//*[name() != "a"]/text()[contains(.,"word")]');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    // can use a Regex in here too if you are after word boundaries
    $node->nodeValue = str_replace('word', 'something', $node->nodeValue);
}
echo $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

Outputs:

```
<html><body><p>
    . text2 text2 something text2...
    <a href="something">text text word <span> something </span> text</a>
    . text2 text2 something text2...
</p><p/></body></html>
```

Note how this will also replace word inside the span inside the a. If you want to exclude those too, you have to adjust the XPath to:

```
'//text()[not(ancestor::a) and contains(., "word")]'
```

to find all text nodes containing the needle that are not nested anywhere inside an a element.

There is a number of third party parsers worth mentioning that aim to enhance [DOM](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php): [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Answer (score 2):

I think to do this with just a regular expression is possible, but cumbersome. So here's a programmatical way, that is, however, dirty.

I would first replace every occurance of `word` by an auxiliary string that doesn't occur in the original string (such as e.g. `@jska_x`). Then I would do a regular expression replacement for `@jska_x` inside an `a`-tag in order to restore the words you do not want to replace.

After all, I would replace `@jska_x` by `target_word`.

Answer (score 2):

```
@\b(word\d+)\b(?![^<>]*</|[^><]*>)@i

<a href="something">text text word1 text</a>. text2 \ (cont. on next line)
<a asdasd> text2 word2 text2... fwefw fwe few fw <a>word3</a> \
<a href="/word5.html">asdada</a>

// don't mind the numbers after word. Used them for detection which word matches
```

Something like this could do the trick, but I advice you not to go with regular expressions on this task. May be you could use DOM and check if word is not in allowed tags, then replace it.